# Invisible mouse cursor plus disabled internet connection on 13.10

Tags: wireless, 13.10, mouse, internet

I am totally new regarding Ubuntu, recently converted from Windows. A friend installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop a few months ago. It's been working great up until about thirty minutes ago.

I booted up the system tonight after having shut it down this morning before work. Upon startup my mouse/cursor is missing, my internet connection is disabled (despite the wireless adapter being switched on and the internet connection working fine on other devices in the house). I am able to use the keyboard and access the terminal, but I don't know the first thing about fixing this issue.

I tried searching the Ubuntu forums and Ask Ubuntu, but I don't see any issues that mimic mine. I also, unfortunately, am unable to offer any sort of system data because I can't access the internet or use the mouse on my laptop to even obtain such data.

I really need help. I can't even begin to speculate how this happened considering everything was working fine at 8 a.m. this morning.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for attempting to help. The problem is fixed. I found that wired connexions were a no go. But a USB mouse allowed me to use my mouse. I attempted updates (not thinking that I wasn't connected to the internet). Not sure if they took, but I rebooted again to attempt another solution I found on here, and when my laptop booted up again everything was fine. Consider this closed - although not ~technically~ solved.

Comment: This could help with the mouse: [Invisible mouse on 14.04 with NVIDIA GeForce4 Ti 4200](http://askubuntu.com/a/502957)

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have similar issue with the cursor. Touchpad gets disabled sometimes. Did you check that. In my laptop, Fn+F3 key combination toggles touchpad on and off. There's a wifi on/off key combination too, which is Fn+F2 in my laptop.

Comment: These were two of the first things I did - no dice. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found out what happened, I had to stop `apt-get` while installing wine, and ever since that happened everything started, anyways I just purged wine (you'll maybe need to purge some other pckg) from the terminal using `aptitude` and everything came back to normal  try doing the same ;)

Oh and to solve the pointer problem so it's easier to fix this try this command:

```
sudo modprobe psmouse
```